# Xmlstarlet / Sh - Copy content of a node into a new node / concat existing

Tags: xml, unix, sh, xmlstarlet

I have the following xml (as example)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gameList>
    <game>
        <path>./sunsetbl.zip</path>
        <name>sunsetbl</name>
        <playcount>8</playcount>
        <lastplayed>20180924T214132</lastplayed>
    </game>
    <game>
        <path>./ssriders.zip</path>
        <name>Sunset Riders (4 Players ver EAC)</name>
        <playcount>4</playcount>
        <lastplayed>20181030T013801</lastplayed>
    </game>
    <game>
        <path>./kof97.zip</path>
        <name>The King of Fighters '97 (NGM-2320)</name>
        <playcount>2</playcount>
        <lastplayed>20181030T035949</lastplayed>
    </game>
    <game>
        <path>./dino.zip</path>
        <name>Cadillacs and Dinosaurs (World 930201)</name>
        <favorite>true</favorite>
        <playcount>26</playcount>
        <lastplayed>20181030T043441</lastplayed>
    </game>
    <game>
        <path>./kof98n.zip</path>
        <name>kof98n</name>
        <playcount>1</playcount>
        <lastplayed>20181031T001024</lastplayed>
    </game>
</gameList>
```

Well, I'm trying to do a sh script and use xmlstarlet on it. For each game node I want to copy the path node and insert it into a new node called description, and if description already exists, concatenate it to the existing text there.

I'm really noob on this and this is what I was able to do until now.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
shopt -s nullglob

for file in *.xml
do
  FILENAME=`xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/gameList/game" -v path $file`;
  echo "Appending $FILENAME into description on $file";
  xmlstarlet ed -L -s "/gameList/game" -t elem -n description -v "$FILENAME" $file;
done
```

Of course, the results sucks, all the path values are together in one line and copied to each game node, this is what it shows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gameList>
  <game>
    <path>./sunsetbl.zip</path>
    <name>sunsetbl</name>
    <playcount>8</playcount>
    <lastplayed>20180924T214132</lastplayed>
    <description>./sunsetbl.zip./ssriders.zip./kof97.zip./dino.zip./kof98n.zip</description>
  </game>
  <game>
    <path>./ssriders.zip</path>
    <name>Sunset Riders (4 Players ver EAC)</name>
    <playcount>4</playcount>
    <lastplayed>20181030T013801</lastplayed>
    <description>./sunsetbl.zip./ssriders.zip./kof97.zip./dino.zip./kof98n.zip</description>
  </game>
  <game>
    <path>./kof97.zip</path>
    <name>The King of Fighters '97 (NGM-2320)</name>
    <playcount>2</playcount>
    <lastplayed>20181030T035949</lastplayed>
    <description>./sunsetbl.zip./ssriders.zip./kof97.zip./dino.zip./kof98n.zip</description>
  </game>
  <game>
    <path>./dino.zip</path>
    <name>Cadillacs and Dinosaurs (World 930201)</name>
    <favorite>true</favorite>
    <playcount>26</playcount>
    <lastplayed>20181030T043441</lastplayed>
    <description>./sunsetbl.zip./ssriders.zip./kof97.zip./dino.zip./kof98n.zip</description>
  </game>
  <game>
    <path>./kof98n.zip</path>
    <name>kof98n</name>
    <playcount>1</playcount>
    <lastplayed>20181031T001024</lastplayed>
    <description>./sunsetbl.zip./ssriders.zip./kof97.zip./dino.zip./kof98n.zip</description>
  </game>
</gameList>
```

I would gladly appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Is there any good reason that you cannot use a separate XSLT file for this purpose? This may be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use a separate XSLT file, the solution would be as follows.
Use this XSLT file (here named `trans.xslt`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Add 'path' value to existing 'description' element -->
    <xsl:template match="description">    
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,../path)" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Create new 'description' element -->
    <xsl:template match="game[not(description)]">  
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*" />
        <description>
            <xsl:value-of select="path" />
        </description>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And call it with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
shopt -s nullglob

for file in *.xml
do
  xmlstarlet tr trans.xslt "$file" > "$file.new.xml"
done
```

This create new files with the extension `filename.new.xml`.

Comment: @zx486 Hey your code worked like a charm! I can now continue adding things to it from here. Thank you!

Comment: An extra question, what about if I want to remove the "./" from the path that is shown on the Description node? I tried substring-after but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: Your approach with `substring-after(...)` was spot-on. So use the expressions `concat(.,substring-after(../path,'./'))` for the `description` template and `substring-after(path,'./')` for the `game` template. This should do the job.

Comment: Hey you are awesome, I have what I wanted. This is what I finally did on the `description` `<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-after(../path,'./'),$newline,.)" />` . (newline is a variable for a new line) This way I can see the name of the game file before the actual description that was scraped, this makes everything easier when you need to organize the duplicated roms on Retropie. If you agree, I would like to share this on Retropie forums, (after improving it a little bit) for everyone who needs this. I'll give you all the credit of course. Thanks again

Comment: Glad I could help you. You can share this if you link both ways.

Comment: oh yes, I just accepted it, sorry, I'm new on this :)